# Find function minimum for discrete variables w/ bounds and constraints

Tags: python, scipy-optimize, mystic, discrete-optimization

I'm trying to find a (relatively) fast way to minimise a function on the set of natural numbers given constraints and bounds. I know the mathematical form of the function and its constraints, so a brute force approach seems slow and not very elegant. What's the best way to go about this problem?

Basically I'm trying to generalise from a functional minimisation on the real numbers using scipy.optimize.minimize to one on the natural numbers. (I'm aware that this is a lot harder)

To make things easy. I'm thinking of something like this
example:

```py
from scipy import optimize

x0 = [0,0]
cons = ({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: 0.4 - x[1]})
bounds = ((0,None),(0,None))
fun = lambda x: (x[0]-1.5)**2 + (x[1]-0.5)**2 + 3

res = optimize.minimize(fun, x0=x0, bounds=bounds, constraints=cons)
print(res)
```

Put differently, I'm looking to add constraints and bounds on

```py
fun = lambda x: (x[0]-1.5)**2 + (x[1]-0.5)**2 + 3
xr = [(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,0),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,0),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3),]
min_idx = min(xr, key=fun)
min_val = fun(min_idx)

print(min_idx,min_val)
```

(I know I could impose them by excluding those values from xr, but that seems very little elegant and less practical for the actual thing I have in mind)

So I'm expecting there to be some sort of different minimiser like scipy.optimize.basinhopping or something from mystic to do the trick? Any suggestions?

Comment: Without knowing more about the minimization problem, I would try branch and bound https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound

Answer (score 3):

I modified your problem slightly, to make it a very little bit harder...

```
  Minimize:
            f(x) = (x0 - 1.5)**2 + (x1 - 0.5)**2 + 3

  Where: 
            0 =< x0
            0 =< x1 < 4.1 - x0
            x0,x1 are integers
```

With mystic, you can solve the problem relatively directly:

```
>>> def objective(x):
...     return (x[0] - 1.5)**2 + (x[1] - 0.5)**2 + 3
... 
>>> bounds = [(0,None)]*2
>>> equations = """
... x1 < 4.1 - x0
... """
>>> 
>>> from mystic.symbolic import generate_penalty, generate_conditions
>>> pf = generate_penalty(generate_conditions(equations))
>>> 
>>> from mystic.constraints import integers
>>> 
>>> @integers()
... def round(x):
...   return x
... 
>>> from mystic.solvers import diffev2
>>> from mystic.monitors import VerboseMonitor
>>> 
>>> result = diffev2(objective, x0=bounds, bounds=bounds, penalty=pf, constraints=round, npop=40, gtol=100, disp=True, full_output=True, itermon=VerboseMonitor())
Generation 0 has ChiSquare: 9364567.500000
Generation 10 has ChiSquare: 7021.500000
Generation 20 has ChiSquare: 3.500000
Generation 30 has ChiSquare: 3.500000
Generation 40 has ChiSquare: 3.500000
Generation 50 has ChiSquare: 3.500000
Generation 60 has ChiSquare: 3.500000
STOP("ChangeOverGeneration with {'tolerance': 0.005, 'generations': 100}")
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 3.500000
         Iterations: 67
         Function evaluations: 2400
>>> 
>>> print(result[0])
[2. 0.]
```

Mystic also has logical operators to couple constraints and penalties, and constraints that restrict potential solutions to discrete values, unique values, etc.

Comment: I should mention that I'm the mystic author.

Comment: Thanks, amazing explanation

Comment: Hey! That's pretty cool! Thank a lot! I was wondering: Since you use "round", the solver will waste a lot of time checking equivalent numbers (say 1.6 and 1.7) for the parameters. I am assuming there is no way to save the solver this extra exercise right?
And on a side-note: Would it make a difference perofrmance-wise to use "int" instead of "round"?

Comment: Not sure what's more performant, `round` or `int`.  Yes, you can actually save the solver easily, as it's serializable.  You can use the class interface to the solvers, instead of the function interface -- so that's the `SaveSolver` method in the `DifferentialEvolutionSolver2` class (instead of `diffev2`)

Comment: in `mystic`, a constraint is a mapping/filtering of search space (i.e. a coordinate transformation), while a penalty is an addition to the cost when constraints are violated.  So constraints are "hard" and penalties are "soft".  Using `round` as a constraint, will basically force the solver to only search the space of integers.

Comment: Okay, thanks! That clears it up. Thanks so much for putting together the example!